# iOS App Freemium to Paid App

Tags: ios, app-store

I have `Freemium` apps in the `AppStore`. Originally it was Paid but I wanted to see if `Freemium` versions make any difference in `Downloads and Sales`. It did make difference - ***`number of downloads increased by 10 times but number of purchases reduced by 2 times`***. So `Freemium` modal didn't work for me. I want to change back to `Paid`.

I do not want to create other versions of the Apps as I have really good reviews on all Apps which I don't want to miss. Can someone please help me if it is possible to convert my Apps to `Paid` and do not allow people to use full functionality who has already downloaded apps but haven't paid?

I will somehow need to detect they have been using old app and not paid. I can do it by releasing an update that store key in the `Keychain` but I don't understand hoe would those users be able to pay at all as `Apple` doesn't charge for the App as it is already downloaded in the past, and they won't be able to use full features as they downloaded freemium app....arghhhhh!!! Not sure if this is even possible but want to hear some of yours thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe paid upgrades are not possible, you will lose profit and you can't do anything about it unless you are willing to create a new app to replace the old one. The move from paid to fremium is a permanent one, you cannot force *existing* users to pay after the app is free.

Comment: I think so I will need to take a huge lost this year!

Comment: @applefreak it won't be as bad as you think! Your users will increase vastly and eventually your profits will increase assuming that the %users paying is constant. Good luck!

Comment: It will be bad because 50k Apps have been already downloaded for free, and only 8k have been purchased!!! Very disappointed that this modal completely failed for me!

Comment: @applefreak well, it depends, what's the rate of download before and after?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to move back to Paid, without giving the previous Freemium users the full version.

To do this, you have to:

- Know the last version of your app that was Paid
- Check the user's purchase receipt (refresh receipt if necessary from Apple)
- Know whether the user has made any in-app purchases during the Freemium period (e.g. every time the user upgraded, you added an 'Upgraded' item to their keychain)

**Switch to Paid**

If you have this information, you go ahead and switch your app back to Paid and:

- Check whether they have made any in-app purchases (via e.g. their keychain 'Upgraded' flag). If they have, give them the functionality - easy. If they haven't then go to the next step.
- Check the user receipt to see what version/date of the app they first downloaded. If it is during the Paid period, upgrade them to full version. If it is not, and the user has not made an in-app purchase, keep them at Freemium.

**Disadvantages**

There are 2 disadvantages I can see with this approach:

1. Any user that downloads the app after Freemium will need access to the Internet for you to confirm their receipt. This means the user might download the full version, then at a later time when they are not connected to the Internet, open the app only to find that they have to Upgrade. Of course once they connect to the Internet and their receipt is validated, they will be upgraded, but in the meantime you might get some bad reviews and angry customers.
2. Your app will now be a Paid app that has In-App purchases. This may confuse users thinking that if they buy your app, they will have to further upgrade via in-app purchases... and put them off.

Of course the advantage is that your Freemium users will stay freemium :)

I have done this myself, and had no problems with the process.