# Effect on iOS provisioning profile and certificate after converting a completely free app to in-app-purchase enabled app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, certificate, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

This could be slightly a vague/open ended question.

In my experience, working with provisioning profile and certificate has been a nightmare especially when the app uses a lot of APNS.

After launching a completely free app and later allowing in-app-purchasing, what type of issues can I expect to encounter?

Example) Will allowing in-app-purchase somehow alter my provisioning profile/certificate which will affect the current APNS setup in my server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS App Freemium to Paid App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534816/ios-app-freemium-to-paid-app)

Comment: Your app entitlements will change, but as long as your app bundle remains the same there shouldn't be any impact or issues

Comment: @Sneak, thanks for the article. I read it, although it is informative, it talks about a different issue than what's mentioned in my question. My question focuses on the effect on provisioning profiles and certificates, but the suggested article focuses on foreseeable issues of going back from freemium to paid. Thanks tho.

Comment: @Paulw11, thanks for the quick comment. My current server that handles APNS has PEM files generated from prov profile and certificate. Won't I have to reset this?

Comment: No. Your certificates do expire and have to be re-issued periodically, but you would need to do this even if you didn't update the app.

Comment: @Paulw11, Thank you.